# Property of unitary operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\Psi(x, y, z)$ and $\Phi(x, y, z)$ be two complex functions in $L^2$ space, and $U$ be an unitary operator in the complex $L^2$ space.

Prove that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (U\Psi)^*(U\Phi) d^3r = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Psi^* \Phi d^3 r$$

Comment: Is your 'function space' an $L^{2}$ space?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes

Comment: You seem to be asking if a unitary operator preserves inner products. If that is the question the answer is definitely yes.

Comment: I am asking how it can be shown that a unitary operator preserves inner products.

Comment: $<x,y> =\frac {||x+y||^{2}-||x-y||^{2}-i(||ix+y||^{2}-||ix-y||^{2})} 2$ Now apply U and use the fact that U is  linear and preserves norms.